# Remove two dots back from end of line

Tags: linux, bash, regex

I need to use regex to remove all text starting at the end of line and going back two dots.

```
gtk2-2.24.22-2.fc20.x86_64
```

becomes

```
gtk2-2.24.22-2
```

This is the output from `rpm -qa` to a text file, and I need to cut off the end.

Comment: Ok, what have you tried? Why didn't it work? What regular expression language family do you need to use? POSIX? Extended POSIX? Perl?

Comment: -1 because this reads as 'gimme the codez!!!!!11!'.

Comment: Hannes is correct. I don't know anything about regex, haven't tried anything, and can't find any good sources to learn from.

Comment: I've found http://www.regular-expressions.info to be a great source of information. Maybe you could at least give us a bit of context – like where you need to use this regex or why? Is it in a Bash script? Or does it need to run platform-independently?

Comment: I'll check that and maybe read the book "Mastering Regular Expressions"

This is the output of `rpm -qa` to a text file and I'd like to cut off the end as mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Do you *need* a regex? I know this is a bit of a cheap solution, but regular expressions are not a solution for everything.

For example, with Bash string manipulation:

```bsh
foo="gtk2-2.24.22-2.fc20.x86_64"
echo ${foo%.*.*} # strip the longest match from the last dot
```

Returns `gtk2-2.24.22-2`.

You can call that on a file like so:

```
foo=$(head -1 file.txt)
echo ${foo%.*.*} > new-file.txt
```

Regular expressions are good at parsing something from the beginning, not from the back, since  they consume in a "greedy" fashion from left to right. It's doable, but you need to be a bit more verbose than what you could do in simple Bash.

Note that what looks like a regex in Bash (`.*`) is not a "real" regular expression. In a real regex, the dot `.` represents all characters, and the `*` means that the previous character (group) is repeated 0–n times. In Bash however, the dot `.` means an actual dot, and the `*` is a wildcard for all characters.

Comment: Even when being greedy, most regex implementations will still try to match the input, being less greedy if needed? So something like `(.*)\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*` will match the full string, but then only capture whatever is before those last two dots. But indeed, your answer might very well be easier, if this is to be done in Bash, which is a good assumption giving it's apparently the output of an `rpm` command.

Comment: You're right. Do you want to post your solution as a separate answer though? I kind of wanted to show that there's always a tradeoff between readability and usefulness of regular expressions.

Comment: Nah, I don't like the question ;-) (But feel free to include it and remove my comments!) But I cannot upvote twice ;-)

Comment: As an aside, just a quick test on my Mac: `echo "gtk2-2.24.22-2.fc20.x86_64"|sed -E 's/^(.*)\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$/\1/'`